# Безопасное общение между субдоменами одного сайта

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc

Какие стандартные средства .NET нужно использовать и в каком порядке, чтобы безопасно передавать данные между произвольными двумя сайтами? Приведите, пожалуйста, пример кода, если это возможно.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

первое что пришло в голову:

[1]WCF.

[2]WebAPI (+шифрование, например).